# $A>0$ , $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{x_i}} = 1$ , $Ax = \rho (A)x$ ,can we say that $\rho (A) = \sum\limits_{i,j = 1}^n {{a_{ij}}{x_j}} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A>0$(i.e, all $a_{ij}>0$).

There is $x>0$(i.e, all $x_{i}>0$) such that:

- $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{x_i}}  = 1$
- $Ax = \rho (A)x$

Can we say that  $\rho (A) = \sum\limits_{i,j = 1}^n {{a_{ij}}{x_j}} $?

(Note: $\rho (A) = \max \{ \left| \lambda  \right|:\lambda $ is eigenvalue of $A$   $\}$)

Comment: Just for reference: The result you're using is called the Perron-Frobenius theorem.

Comment: On the other hand, what the OP wants to prove has absolutely nothing to do with Perron-Frobenius theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If you have $Ax = \rho(A) x$, sum up all rows. You'll get $\sum\limits_{i, j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_j = \rho(A) \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i$. If $x$ has some special properties, it could be simplified further.